# Whats App+ in Moto G

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, whatsapp-messenger, motorola-moto-g

Recently i bought a Moto G phone. When i tried to install Whats app+ in it, it won't allow SMS verification as well as voice verification.My Android version is 4.4. I also enabled install from third party apps. I don't know what is the problem with it. Please suggest me some solution .

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall Whatsapp plus and delete Whatsapp folder using file manager.
2. Install official Whatsapp from Play Store and Verify your number.
3. After complition of verification, just chat with few and then Uninstall Whatsapp.
4. Now finally install Whatsapp Plus and this time it will verify your number.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Whats app+ is down. They infringes the rights of use of whatsapp.

Comment: Tat means we can't use whats app+ here after or what ? Since i have it working perfectly in my old mobile(samsung). Why it can't be able to install in New one (moto g)

Comment: An application made for old mobile which is running on an older Android OS might not work on newest Android OS. Its all about compatibility. Get it?

Comment: @MANI But WhatsApp+ is not made for older mobile rite. I even downloaded the .apk file newly and tried but fails.